# issue with char TypeDef

Tags: c++, typedef

When I try to copy the data from a string into this typdef char by char, the debugger shows everything going in properly, but when it ouputs, it outputs the data plus garbage data. When I tried to see the length of the items each instance of scores, the size is over 700, when it should be 30. Anyone know whats going on?

```
const int NUMBEROFQUESTIONS= 30;
typedef char answerSet[NUMBEROFQUESTIONS];

getline(testResults, x, '\n');
        testResults.getline(scores[count],'\n');

        for(int j=0; j< 25; j++){
            for(int i =0; i < 30;i++){
                scores[j][i] = x[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: `typedef char answerSet[NUMBEROFQUESTIONS];` this does not make sense at all...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: he's defining a type called `answerSet` which is an array of `NUMBEROFQUESTIONS` elements of type `char`. http://ideone.com/iEJ9EZ. user2966767: please provide a short compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @user2093113 I meant in his code, it doesn't mean anything, I can't see any variable of `answerSet` type...

Comment: Please show us how your variables are defined by posting the smallest amount of code that compiles and exhibits the problem.  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should put trailing '\0' at the end of your array if you want to see output as string.